# Example of class object implementing operator[] using an initializer-list as the function argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, initializer-list

[[expr.sub]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#4) allows an initializer-list to be passed as an argument of `operator[]` for an object of class type. What would be a practical example using this technique?

Comment: Why do you tag language-lawyer?  I don't think the answer to this question can be found in the standard.

Comment: @L.F. If I can't find an example for this use, I'll have a strong indication that the grammar production _postfix-expression_ `:`  _postfix-expression_ `[` _expr-or-braced-init-list_ `]` could be simplified. With this in mind, I'm rolling back  your edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the standard allowing one thing doesn't necessarily mean you can easily find a practical example of its usage.  The fact that the standard allows something isn't inherently language lawyering.  I believe your actual question is "what is the rationale for allowing a braced-init-list in `[]`", which isn't a language-lawyer question.  If not, then you should clarify your question.

Comment: @L.F.  Well,I disagree with your statement above: "what is the rationale for allowing a braced-init-list in []", which isn't a language-lawyer question.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390168/1364007).

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/over.sub has an example

Comment: @Mat I have seen this example somewhere else, but unfortunately it doesn't define the operator function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: A map with the key being a tuple seems like an obvious case

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be used to subscript a multi-dimensional array if you really want to avoid abusing `operator()`, something like this:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
class Multi_array {
public:
    // ...
    reference operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& index)
    {
        return elems[flatten(index)];
    }
    const_reference operator[](const std::array<std::size_t, N>& index) const
    {
        return elems[flatten(index)];
    }
    // ...
};
```

then you can use `arr[{3, 1, 4}]`.